# VB.Net/Visual Studio - Find all uses of string equality operator

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio, compare

Language: VB.Net

Visual Studio Version: 15.9.35

.Net Framework Version: 4.8.04084

I recently came across an error in an application I'm maintaining: one line of code uses the equality operator `=` to compare two strings and the code failed when one string was in titlecase and one in lowercase (as should have been expected; `Option Compare Binary` is on by default). I am now concerned that there may be other cases in the code (something like 15,000 lines) where this may be an issue and I would like to find all uses of `=` to compare two string values. Searching for all occurrences of `=` is less than ideal (I know I'll miss some if I try to inspect every single use of `=` visually), and I don't want to switch the `Option Compare` to `Text` if I can avoid it, in case there are instances where case-sensitivity is desired, so what I'm looking for is a way of locating all uses of `=` to compare (not assign) strings and only strings.

Is there a way of doing this in Visual Studio? To be frank I wouldn't expect there to be as I can't see it making the must-do list of features. If not, is there some other way I can search for these instances? I could write an application to search for all strings and then look for `if` statements that use the `=` sign for equality but I'm pressed for time so I would prefer to use a tried and tested alternative.

Any help or suggestions (even a frame challenge if I've missed something fundamental) would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `the code failed when one string was in titlecase and one in lowercase` - Before comparing, you can convert all strings to uppercase or lowercase. Or use `String.Equals("A", "a", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` instead of `=`.

Comment: @XingyuZhao - thanks for the comment, but I'm aware of the options; I just don't know how to search to find all the places I should be making changes. I need to find all instances of `If (x = y)` but _only_ where `x` and `y` are both strings.

Comment: You can use ['Find and replace'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2019) in visual studio, but it cannot guarantee that  `x` and `y` are both strings because it's only known at runtime.

Comment: Hi @XingyuZhao - all strings are declared as such:

`Dim x As String = "a"
Dim y As String = "b"

If (x = y) Then...`

That's what I'm looking for; x and y are both known to be strings and the `=` operator has been used for comparison.